# Durring npm install: fs.js... binding.copyFile... Unknown system error -122

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting the following when installing `@sentry/cli@1.39.1` in a fresh `node_modules` (existing project). Needed for `@sentry/webpack-plugin`.

**Is there any way I can find out more about this "unknown system error -122"?** The npm debug log has no more info on the error than below.

```
user@host ~/project $ rm -rf node_modules
user@host ~/project $ npm install --no-save @sentry/cli@1.39.1

> @uirouter/core@5.0.5 install /home/user/project/node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/node_modules/@uirouter/core
> node ./migrate/migratewarn.js


> strong-ursa@0.10.1 install /home/user/project/node_modules/strong-ursa
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/user/project/node_modules/strong-ursa/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative.node
  COPY Release/ursaNative.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/project/node_modules/strong-ursa/build'

> @uirouter/angularjs@1.0.5 install /home/user/project/node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs
> node migrate/migratewarn.js


> @sentry/cli@1.39.1 install /home/user/project/node_modules/@sentry/cli
> node scripts/install.js

fs.js:1918
  binding.copyFile(src, dest, flags);
          ^

Error: Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, copyfile '/home/user/.npm/sentry-cli/75353c-sentry-cli-Linux-x86-64' -> '/home/user/project/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli'
    at fs.copyFileSync (fs.js:1918:11)
    at downloadBinary (/home/user/project/node_modules/@sentry/cli/scripts/install.js:112:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/project/node_modules/@sentry/cli/scripts/install.js:178:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @sentry/cli@1.39.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @sentry/cli@1.39.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when I upgraded node to > v8

```
fs.js:1919
  binding.copyFile(src, dest, flags);
```

The solution was to upgrade my npm packages using `npm audit fix`
I am not sure which of the many packages upgraded solved the problem